# iOS App Store user review notification

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

Is there anyway to get notified when a user posts a review of your app in the app store? E.g. it would be nice to get an email every time a new review of my app is posted.

Comment: In the ideal scenario, your app has thousands upon thousands of (good) reviews. Are you sure you want to receive that many emails??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because questions about app-stores are off-topic https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though you do not want to log into itunesconnect and look for reviews every day.  Try signing up for a service like appannie.com  It is free and they send you a daily email with downloads from the previous day and any new reviews that you have received.